# How do I write multiple CSV files from a list of data frames?

Tags: r, csv

I have a list with two data frames. I want to loop thru the list and write a CSV for each data frame and name it after the data frame name.

```
library(ggplot2)
myList <- list(diamonds, cars)
for(i in mylist){
  write.csv(df, paste0(names(myList[i]),".csv"))
}
```

But this only outputs one CSV file names `.csv` with data from `cars`.

How do I fix this so I have two CSVs named `diamonds.csv` and `cars.csv` with the correct data in each?

Comment: Fyi, generally a good idea to make your example reproducible on its own. In this case, it breaks because diamonds is not in base R. You  can add a `library(whatever_package)` line to the code to fix it.

Comment: @Frank or just `data("diamonds",package="ggplot2")`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A few of things.

1. `myList` doesn't have any names, so you aren't actually naming your files.
2. Once you give `myList` names, you would do better to index along the names than along the list
3. You use `df` in your `for` loop, but that isn't defined anywhere.

This should work (untested)

```
myList <- list(diamonds = diamonds, 
               cars = cars)
for(i in names(mylist)){
  write.csv(myList[[i]], paste0(i,".csv"))
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also use `mapply`:

```
myList <- list(diamonds = diamonds, 
               cars = cars)
mapply(write.csv, myList, file=paste0(names(myList), '.csv'))
```