# Loop over a list of tables and write to csv in R

Tags: r

Good people, I have a list of tables that I do want to write each with unique names to CSV.I have  tried this method but it isn't working,

```
diff<- c(1,2,3,4)

for (i in 1:length(diff)){

  write.table(1+1, "test.csv")

}
```

This is a list of tables and my expected output is to write every table in that list to CSV and save them with different names.

Comment: Did you see this one? [How do I write multiple CSV files from a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356375/how-do-i-write-multiple-csv-files-from-a-list-of-data-frames).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
List.of.tables #some list of tables

for(i in seq_along(List.of.tables)){
  write.csv2(List.of.tables[[i]], paste0("Table_", i,".csv"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exemple to adapt :

```r
data_list = list("iris" = iris, "mtcars" = mtcars)
data_list_names <- names(data_list)

for (i in 1:length(data_list) ){

        write.table( data_list[[i]], data_list_names[[i]] )

}
```